# Translation for "cold" (I have a cold)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which word would you recommend to translate "I have a cold"?

> die Verkühlung (en)
>   die Erkältung (en)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Duden, the standard written German translation of *catch cold* is *[sich erkälten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erkaelten#Bedeutung1a).* The corresponding noun is *[die Erkältung](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Erkaeltung).*

Duden – *Das Stilwörterbuch* shows some typical expressions:

> **erkälten:**
> **a)** <sich erkälten> *sich eine Erkältung zuziehen:*
> ich habe mich erkältet
> sie ist sehr erkältet
>
> **Erkältung,** die:
> eine leichte Erkältung
> eine schwere Erkältung
> die Erkältung klingt ab
> sich eine Erkältung zuziehen
> (umgangssprachlich) sich eine Erkältung holen
> (umgangssprachlich) sich eine Erkältung einfangen
> eine Erkältung haben
> eine Erkältung bekommen
> eine Erkältung auskurieren
> Erkältungen durch Abhärtung vorbeugen
> sie leidet an einer heftigen Erkältung
> sich vor Erkältung[en] schützen.

Regional expressions for *sich erkälten* are *sich verkühlen* and *sich verkälten.*
A map of the distribution is shown in the *[Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f15/):*

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Comment: I'd like to add that "Verkühlung" is in fact standard written German in the region where it is used at all (Austria); this is distinct from other regional expressions which are considered non-standard or dialect.

Comment: I would change the red dots to "erkälten"! Well, I live there.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend:

> Ich habe eine Erkältung.

But you can also say:

> Ich habe mich erkältet.
>
> Ich habe mich verkühlt.

The substantive `Verkühlung` is not a common expression (at least in my region).

Comment: Where do you come from? What is your region or country?

Comment: @Elisabetta In this case his region is the entirety of Germany. ;) – I believe they say *Verkühlung* in Austria.

Comment: I live in Austria. Here we say "Verkühlung".

Comment: Also a valid translation: Ich habe einen Schnupfen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast is Schnupfen more common than Verkühlung in Austria?

Comment: Beim Schnupfen will man die Betonung auf die laufende Nase legen. Bei der Verkühlung aber eher auf das Fieber und die Gliederschmerzen. Man kann eine Verkühlung haben ohne gleichzeitig einen Schnupfen zu haben, auch der umgekehrte Fall ist denkbar. Aber soviel ich weiß gibt es für Schnupfen, Erkältung und Verkühlung nur die englischen Übersetzungen "flu" und "cold", die aber beide keinen Unterschied hinsichtlich der Menge des gebildeten Nasensekrets machen. Ich kann mich bei der Bedeutung der englischen Wörter aber auch irren.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Einen Schnupfen haben" with article? In (Western) Germany, we'd just say "Ich habe Schnupfen".

Comment: @Em1: Ja. Bei uns sagt man: »Hans hat eine Erkältung, und Lisa hat einen Schnupfen.« Dsa ohne Artikel zu sagen klingt für mich seltsam: »Hans hat Erkältung, und Lisa hat Schnupfen.« - Ne. Bitte beide Male mit Artikel!

Comment: In (Ost-)Österreich wirst du zusätzlich auch "Ich bin verkühlt" hören.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to comment, but don't have enough reputation for this.

> Ich habe mich verkühlt.

could be only used in some countries. As a native German, I would say, that this is not correct (or at least not in South-Germany).

As hellcode recommended, you should say:

> Ich habe eine Erkältung.

In Germany a *Erkältung* can refer to *Schnupfen*, which means you have to sneeze a lot and/or *Husten*, which is translated as *cough*.

Comment: "verkühlt" (plattdeutsch "verkeult") wird in Norddeutschland doch schon mal verwendet.